# "Compare a variable by state abbreviations

Tags: r

How can I compare a variable by state abbreviations?

My data set has 5 variables currently. One of them is Location, and it is written as: "Raleigh, NC"

I need to create a variable that contains the two-character state abbreviation for each observation, and afterward another to group them by state. Each observation is of a college including their classification(private/public), instate/out of state tuition, and location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do for you, if I understood your issue correctly.

**Note**: Please always share sample data using `dput(your_dataset)` or  `dput(head(your_dataset))`

```
library(tidyverse)
d<- tibble(id = 1:3,
           Location = c("Newyork, NY", "Raleigh, NC", "Delhi, IN"))
d %>% separate(Location,into = c("city", "country")) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars("city","country"), str_trim)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
     id city    country
  <int> <chr>   <chr>  
1     1 Newyork NY     
2     2 Raleigh NC     
3     3 Delhi   IN
```

Comment: Since they're all the last two digits I actually used:
tibble$States = str_sub(tibble$Location, -2)

Comment: This would also work in case of **States**, however, in case of **city** it won't as length is not fixed. Also, I recommend using either `separate` or `str_split` as they would do the job in one simple step.